# Facebook authorization trouble in Android

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to integrate facebook with android mobile, all i need to do is to take some text from my application and put it as status on Facebook, i have tried facebook_sdk for the purpose, when i saw the debugging mode, the application is terminating at the line facebook.authorize(), though there is full internet connectivity in menifest... below is my code:
Thanks in advance

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button1);
    button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button2);
    tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
    et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            b1Click();
        }

    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            b2Click();
        }

    });
}
private void saveFBToken(String token, long tokenExpires){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    prefs.edit().putString("FacebookToken", token).commit();
}

private void fbAuthAndPost(final String message){

    facebook.authorize(this, new String[]{"publish_stream"},new   DialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),"Facebook.authorize Complete: ");
            saveFBToken(facebook.getAccessToken(), facebook.getAccessExpires());
            updateStatus(values.getString(Facebook.TOKEN), message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),"Facebook.authorize Error: "+error.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),"Facebook.authorize DialogError: "+e.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),"Facebook authorization canceled");
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode){
    case Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH:
        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

private void b1Click(){

    mAuthAttempts = 0;

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    mFacebookToken = prefs.getString("FacebookToken", "");

    if(mFacebookToken.equals("")){
        fbAuthAndPost(et1.getText().toString());
    }else{
        updateStatus(mFacebookToken,et1.getText().toString());
    }
}

private void b2Click(){
    mAuthAttempts = 0;
    updateStatus(facebook.TOKEN,et1.getText().toString());
}

public void updateStatus(String accessToken, String message){
    try {         
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("message", message);         
        bundle.putString(Facebook.TOKEN,accessToken);         
        String response = facebook.request("me/feed",bundle,"POST");         
        Log.d("UPDATE RESPONSE",""+response);
        showToast("Update process complete. Respose:"+response);
        if(response.indexOf("OAuthException") > -1){
            if(mAuthAttempts==0){
                mAuthAttempts++;
                fbAuthAndPost(message);
            }else{
                showToast("OAuthException:");
            }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {         
        Log.e("MALFORMED URL",""+e.getMessage());
        showToast("MalformedURLException:"+e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {         
        Log.e("IOEX",""+e.getMessage());
        showToast("IOException:"+e.getMessage());
    }

    String s = facebook.getAccessToken()+"\n";
    s += String.valueOf(facebook.getAccessExpires())+"\n";
    s += "Now:"+String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())+"\n";
    tv1.setText(s);
} 
private void showToast(String message){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: put the logcat...that will reveal the error details.

Comment: Please put your facebook api's class i can solve your problem..
Sure..

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException : Resource ID #0x7f020005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would appreciate some details on the error you receive before the app crashes Like Usama said the logcat would be great. I can't see where do you initialize the variable facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);. Make sure that you have also all the activities facebook is using in your manifest. Finally I let you this:
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/examples/simple/src/com/facebook/android/Example.java

I hope that some of this helps.

<< When you try to log in to the Facebook page,  you receive a Token if thee user and the password were correct, this means that the application has a valid user loged in to the facebook servers. The SessionStore class saves that token in your shared preferences. So then you can use the Token to connect to facebook again later without asking the password to the user. You can do this only if the session hasn't expired.
About the error:
"This exception is thrown by the resource APIs when a requested resource can not be found."

I did the facebook integration a long time ago, and for a company so I can't pass you the code because I don't have it. Look at this post maybe it helps. http://www.jiahaoliuliu.com/2011/05/android-runtime-error.html

I'll look around to see if I find something more explicit.

Comment: i don't understand SessionStore class, as it is not present in the facebook_sdk.jar i am using.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException : Resource ID #0x7f020005

Answer (score 0):

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
```

is fired sometimes 'cause in Idea you might have overwritten English string resources when importing project.